# How to view end edit html files on iPhone using files app?

Tags: html, iphone, file, view, edit

How do I edit and view html files using the files app?

(The files app is an app provided with the phone)

I can’t seem to find any option such as “new file”.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new file or edit a file through the Files app. To do that you would have to use another app such as Coda.

You can find some more apps here:
https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-ipad-html-editor-apps/